# L'usage métaphorique du mot "robuste" / Metaphorical use of "robuste"

Tags: sens

Si je disais "Leurs conclusions étaient robustes" pour dire que leur conclusions étaient sensées, cela aurait-il du sens?

If I said "Leurs conclusions étaient robustes" to mean their conclusions were sound, does this make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qualifier des conclusions de *robustes* ne relève pas d'un usage métaphorique du mot, mais d'un usage normal. *Robuste* est synonyme de *solide*, *résistant* et  peut être employé pour qualifier des objets, des personnes ou des concepts.

Dictionnaire Larousse en ligne:
**Robuste**

> Littéraire.  Qui ne se laisse pas ébranler facilement : Rien ne peut entamer ses robustes certitudes.([source](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/robuste/69655))

Quelques exemples avec « conclusions robustes » :

> Dans cette analyse, on cherche à exhiber des conclusions et solutions robustes dans un problème d'investissement sous contrainte budgétaire dans un environnement incertain. ([source](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00180651))
>
> Dans le présent rapport comme dans le TRE, on entend par conclusion robuste en matière de changements climatiques toute conclusion qui reste valable pour un large éventail de démarches, de méthodes, de modèles et d’hypothèses et qui devrait généralement le rester malgré les incertitudes. ([source](https://www.ipcc.ch/publications_and_data/ar4/syr/fr/mains6.html))

On peut l'employer pour qualifier un programme informatique :

> se dit d'un programme informatique capable de fonctionner dans des conditions non nominales (erreur de saisie...). - Le programme est robuste aux retours de ligne en trop. ([source](http://dicocitations.lemonde.fr/dico-mot-definition/121048/robuste.php))
>
> Le langage Java permet de réaliser des programmes robustes. Il a été conçu pour réaliser des logiciels embarqués. ([source](http://www-inf.it-sudparis.eu/cours/CSC4002/EnLigne/Cours/CoursJAVA/2.3.9.html))

Des conclusions robustes sont des conclusions qui sont capables de résister à toute réfutation, c'est dans cette mesure qu'on peut dire qu'elles sont sensées, mais *sensé* n'est pas directement synonyme de *robuste*.

Answer (score 2):

*Sensé* n'est pas directement une bonne interprétation pour *robuste*: *robuste* ici fait référence à une *solidité* des conclusions (elle vont être difficiles ou impossible à réfuter), ce qui est très différent de *sensé*, qui voudrait dire que les conclusions sont *compréhensibles*, peut-être dérivent-elles d'un *bon sens* partagé, en tout cas, elles ne sont pas extrêmes (et par là difficiles à accepter).

*Robuste* n'est pas adéquat pour traduire le mot anglais *sound*, pour la même raison, et aussi parce que *sound* en anglais a un sens technique en [logique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundness) (valide et sémantiquement vrai), qui n'est pas du tout reflété par *robuste*. *Robuste* a également un usage technique en [statistiques](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robust_statistics) (relativement insensible aux valeurs extrêmes non-significatives). Un autre sens technique du mot *robuste*, probablement le plus courant, est tout simplement *résistant* (aux pannes, défauts, conditions de l'environnement...).
On voit bien comment ces différents sens sont congruents, mais les différences ne sont pas négligeables non plus, et ne semblent pas du tout faire partie du mot anglais *sound*.

Au vu de ces sens du mot *robuste*, on peut l'utiliser pour parler de *conclusions*. Des *conclusions robustes* seraient des conclusions qui sont bien étayées par les faits, et sur lesquelles on peut baser des décisions effectives. Ceci reflèterait sans doute une bonne santé *rationnelle* du processus qui aboutit auxdites conclusions, donc on pourrait dire que les décisions sont *sensées*.

Mais une autre traduction du mot *sound*, peut-être meilleure quand il s'agit de conclusions, serait simplement [*correctes*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correction_(logique)): "*leurs conclusions étaient correctes*". Cette traduction a le mérite de rester proche du sens de *sound* en logique, ce qui est sans doute désirable ici, puisqu'il s'agit de conclusions... Vous pourriez utiliser *valide*, mais cela indiquerait instantanément une confusion sur, ou méconnaissance de, l'utilisation de ces deux termes en logique élémentaire, donc à éviter, au profit de *correct*.